# javascript continue doesn't advance 'for in' iterator?

Tags: javascript, continue

I'm trying to iterate through all the elements of an object (which is either an Array or Object) as follows:

```
for (i in values) {
    if (!values.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue
    // do a bunch of stuff here
}
```

But I'm finding that if `values` is an Array I get stuck in an infinite loop.  When I try to debug it in Chrome's developer tools, I see that `i` seems to be "stuck" with a value of `"contains"`.

Does `continue` not advance the iterator to the next value of `i` or is something else going on that the debugger is obscuring?  I have checked my code in the loop and I am not modifying `values` nor `i` but from what I have read `continue` should advance the iterator.

Comment: Try adding `var` in `for(var i in values)`

Comment: Not the case [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/vkWKA/)  What's in your array?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/a39zK/). Could you share any more details?

Comment: well the loop is about 30 lines of code, most of which I *thought* should be extraneous to the matter of hand and would just confuse the issue to show.  but i'll try to see if I can find a simplest case that still manifests the symptoms.

Comment: well i've got a couple of loops that are doing some DOM manipulation (appendChild, removeChild, etc.) as well as calling some other functions... if I try a simplified version without DOM and just one of the loops (the other doesn't make sense without DOM because it's just stepping through chld nodes) the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Are you appending items that match the original selection? Some DOM lists are "live lists".

Comment: ...and why use `for (var i in values) { if (!values.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue` when you could just do `for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {`? Much shorter and faster.

Comment: @cookiemonster ok a bit more experimenting: the jsfiddles don't show the problem but the exact same code in my file hangs. copied a skeleton of my code to jsfiddle and it works.

Comment: @cookiemonster if I pass an object, it doesn't have a length property

Comment: It sounds like the list is being extended somehow during the iteration. Can't tell without seeing the code though.

Comment: What if you factor out the loop part? As in `loop_2` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/7Bc9m/)..

Comment: @user13500 yeah that seems to be a valid workaround, but I'm not sure why it is necessary.  Seems like any simpler test cases I come up with don't have this problem, so I'm not sure why my code specifically gets into an infinite loop.  Browser bug maybe?

Comment: @user13500 also, `if (values instanceof Array)` is a simpler test.

Comment: I thought mostly of using it in a debugging phase.